# Cloud Run On Anthos - VPC access only

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, google-anthos

I have deployed a service on Cloud Run Anthos. Access to the service is only through VPC private connection and not to be exposed to outside. I have a VM and trying to access the service and not able to connect on the internal IP. Can this service be accessed only through GKE cluster external IP with a valid domain? It doesn't make sense with option provided with Anthos deployment that allow access only through internal "This service is deployed in a `cluster-local configuration`, and can only be reached from inside the Kubernetes cluster. You can use `kubectl port-forward` to set up a tunnel from your desktop to the cluster"

Is internal means, not the GCP project context but only within the cluster?

[gke-workloads-anthos-cloud-run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QghG3.png)
[anthos-cluster-cloud-run-service-deployed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osbru.png)

```
[cloud-run-anthos-gke][3]
```

```
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8iE9.png
```

Comment: Can you share how is exposed the service?

Comment: Please check the images. Let me know if you need anything else. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access to the service from outside, you need to expose it with NodePort. In ClusterIP mode, it is only accessible from inside the cluster

More detail in the [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/)

Comment: I don't want to access it from outside. The service should be accessed within the VPC and the GCP project by other components running within the project.

Comment: Figured it out. Quite clumsy but works. Set up a cloud DNS  with a private zone for the default network for the project. Get the internal cluster IP where the cloud run service is deployed and create a record with a subdomain. In cloud run for the service add this domain. Here's the clumsy part. The IP for the domain under cloud run will point to cluster's external IP. It won't let you change it even though the cloud run service was set up for internal.

Comment: GCP should point the internal IP for GKE cluster assigned for the service rather than external. Domain validation will fail as the public DNS record is not updated. BUT, I can access the service internally using the subdomain name.

Comment: Kubernetes is sometime tricky. But glad to hear that is working now :)